# Kivy Installation Guide for Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I've been trying to follow online youTube videos to install kivy on my Windows 10 computer (python-3.7.5-amd64, kivy 1.11.1). Aside from the fact that they seem to have different variations on how they approach the topic, I am unable to get a solution that operates satisfactorily.

These are the steps I am following:

- I install python (python-3.7.5-amd64.exe) to C:\Python37
- I modify the path to include to include the following: C:\Python37\Scripts;C:\Python37;C:\Python37\Libs;C:\Python37\DLLs;C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages;
- I added the following environment variable PYTHONPATH = C:\Python37\DLLs;C:\Python37\Libs;C:\Python37;C:\Python37\Scripts;C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages;
- I open a command window and type in the following commands (taken from kivy.org)

  - python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools virtualenv
  - python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.* kivy_deps.glew==0.1.*
  - python -m pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.*
  - python -m pip install kivy_deps.angle==0.1.*
  - python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
  - python -m pip install kivy_examples==1.11.1
- I try to run a simple program. From within Windows Explorer I right click the code file (label.py) and from the shortcut menu select python.
- A windows pops up for an instant and a directory called **__pycache__** gets created with **kivy.cpython-37.pyc**. Double clicking that causes the program to run.
- *Is it possible to have a easier solution in which the source code, once compiled executes?*

If I open a command prompt and attempt to execute the source code using the command **python label.py** I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "label.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
  File "C:\Users\chrib\Google Drive\_Software\Python_Kivy\kivy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.base'; 'kivy' is not a package
```

Why should this happen?

Also is it possible to have a *cleaner* development environment.  I am used to Visual Studio IDE and it would be great if I can use this environment.

Thanks

Code for label.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return Label(text='Hello world!');

if __name__=='__main__':
  MyApp().run();
```

Comment: Please share the label.py file

Comment: Code added - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had a program in the code directory called kivy.py.  I renamed that and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

> I've been trying to follow online youTube videos to install kivy on my Windows 10 computer

Have you tried simply following the instructions on kivy.org? There's no need to use youtube videos, the installation is largely a normal python module install.

> I try to run a simple program. From within Windows Explorer I right click the code file (label.py) and from the shortcut menu select python.

Don't do this, run the file by opening a command prompt and typing `python yourfilename.py`. That way you will see the full traceback for any errors that occur.

> A windows pops up for an instant and a directory called **pycache** gets created with kivy.cpython-37.pyc. Double clicking that causes the program to run.

It sounds likely that the first run is crashing. As above, you want to get the information about why.

> Is it possible to have a easier solution in which the source code, once compiled executes?

When you run the code it *does* execute. As above, it's probably crashing.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.base'; 'kivy' is not a package

Have you made a file named `kivy.py`? It looks likely that you have, and that this file is being imported in preference to the installed kivy module.

> Also is it possible to have a cleaner development environment. I am used to Visual Studio IDE and it would be great if I can use this environment.

I'm not sure what you consider unclean about your development environment, but you should think in terms of python environments and their installed packages. Kivy is just a python module that you install into a python environment. When you use an IDE, it may integrate with one or more python environments (with options to switch between them). There's nothing special about using Visual Studio with Kivy, just do whatever you normally do to use it with Python.

Comment: My definition of clean is that I am experiencing considerable hassle focusing on even getting to environment to work.  At the moment I am unable to consistently get the same code to execute two times in a row.

I uninstalled everything and reinstalled the 64bit version of python 3.7.5.  I then followed the kivy installation for windows implementing the optional *virtual environment*.

I moved the code to a sub-directory under C:\Python37 and it ran.  

I opened a new CMD and enabled the environment but got an error.

Comment: `

`c:\Python37>kivy_venv\Scripts\activate
    
    (kivy_venv) c:\Python37>python.exe acb\label.py    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "acb\label.py", line 1, in <module>
        from kivy.app import App
      File "c:\Python37\acb\kivy.py", line 1, in <module>
        from kivy.base import runTouchApp   
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.base'; 'kivy' is not a package`

Comment: Sorry but I seem unable to format the previous comment as a code. I seem unable to insert line breaks

Comment: To quote myself: Have you made a file named kivy.py? It looks likely that you have, and that this file is being imported in preference to the installed kivy module.

Comment: What is the result of `import kivy; print(kivy.__file__)`?

Comment: you were right. It was picking a kivy.py from the directory of the code.